# "Clean Project" doesn't work in Android Studio: How to use it properly?

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Due to various problems/bugs I had to face in **Android Studio 1.2.1**. I moved to **Android Studio 1.1**. I create a new project. There is no rendering problem.

I casually /unmindfully double click on the `"Hello World"` string in the display view and click on the ID box. Oops I didn't want to touch the ID creation there but since I had clicked now, the project gets unstable  and gives me the error `"It cannot be left blank"` . Fine I can't do anything now(it doesn't automatically correct/create it). Anyway, to correct it, I go to the Text view, manually delete the ID entries from Views(I don't need the IDs for now). Error still persists. I then clean the project, it stops in the middle; the errors won't go away. It won't rebuild either. I am stuck now

So my question is, How do you correct the resource linking errors if ever you accidentally happen to click/modify any such entry or setting?

**EDIT 1:** The R.java file got regenerated only after I closed and reopened the project. So, isn't there a way without doing it? Doing this slows down productivity somewhat.

Comment: it's really weird what you are explaining. if you change a view id, the R file will be regenerated. If it's not you have an error in you're xml somewhere. To prevent this you could use a VCS and just cancel the modified file.

Comment: @HugoGresse : You are right. It did but only after I closed and then reopened the project. I mean isn't there a way that it happens in real time? Closing and reopening any project many times just slows down productivity.

Comment: it happen in real time. Something could be wrong else where. Are you sure you're not editing generated file or something like this ?

Comment: @HugoGresse : No I haven't touched it at all. Infact it is so unintuitive to find it.

Comment: you could post a sample project to we can see what you're doing. I don't think is a AS1.1 issue as I was already using it.

Comment: @HugoGresse : Sample project? Nothing, I just created a new Android Project. That's it. Not even a single line of code.

Comment: @HugoGresse : It is gone after reopening but I still want to know, what that clean does?